# Roslyn ObjectPool struct wrapper

Tags: c#, arrays, generics, struct, roslyn

I am looking at the Roslyn ObjectPool implementation ( https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/blob/master/src/Compilers/Core/SharedCollections/ObjectPool%601.cs ) and I don't get why they did not simply choose to have an array of T but instead wrap T inside a struct?

```
[DebuggerDisplay("{Value,nq}")] 
private struct Element 
{ 
    internal T Value; 
} 
...
private readonly Element[] _items;
```

What is the purpose of this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a common trick to avoid performance problems when setting array items that are reference types. Arrays are variant on the CLR (and on the JVM). You can write a `string` into an `object[]`. This requires a runtime check that you are not actually storing a string into a `SomethingElse[]`. With that value type trick it's not necessary to perform that check at runtime.

Comment: But `ObjectPool` over there doesn't set any element to the array. It rely on the fact that array of struct is initialized with zeroed struct instances.

Comment: Well, *something* is going to set `Value`. What's point if nothing ever sets that value?! That code is just not shown here.

Comment: Yes some code sets the field `Value`. But nothing overwrites the element in an array. Given that `Value` is a field, There is no type checking there in runtime. it invalidates your answer. Isn't it?

Comment: No, that's the point. The point is *removing* the runtime check *due to* the struct being the element type. Without it there would be a runtime check.

Comment: Fair enough. I can intuitively understand that there is no runtime checks needed here. But is there a post or something talks about this where I can read more?

Comment: I've just created a performance test ( https://gist.github.com/anonymous/3c9a3a0f71bd09e0d8f2 ) and it looks like @usr is right under certain conditions. Both seem to perform equally well when assigning objects of the array element type (using .NET 4.6 x64). However when assigning a derived object the struct wrapper version is 3 times faster. With .Net 3.5 x64 the struct version is even faster when the right type is used.

Comment: From the generated assembly code I see that for the array version an JIT_Ldelema_Ref is emitted which contains the type check whereas the struct version can do a direct load of the address. See https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/master/src/vm/jithelpers.cpp for more details.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18802569/when-to-use-an-array-of-a-value-type-containing-a-reference-types-over-an-array question is different, answers are 100% the same. I don't think this qualifies for a dupe closure.

Answer (score 1):

I believe it is for performance reasons. Array of struct is a friend to garbage collector as opposed to  Array of class.

From [5 Tips and Techniques for Avoiding Automatic GC Collections](https://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/.net-framework/5-tips-and-techniques-for-avoiding-automatic-gc-collections/)

> With an array of class instances, the GC has to check each item in
>   that array to see if it is a live object or not (the same is true for
>   generic collections, which use an internal array). With an array of
>   structs, the GC just looks to see if the array itself is still a live
>   object, since structs cannot be null (this is true even for
>   Nullable structs, which just use an internal tracking mechanism to
>   determine nullity). So that is potentially thousands or even millions
>   of items that the GC does not need to examine when a collection runs!

Comment: If that was true the CLR would just always wrap all array elements and not need to GC them... Even an array of structs must be traversed if it holds references.

Comment: @usr I see where you're coming from. Even I was skeptical when I first read the article. Maybe author meant that it only means to an array of struct which doesn't contain any references. We've to reach the author to know more details.

Comment: The GC can only skip arrays of value types if the type itself contains no references. Otherwise it still has to go through the array.